# IMFMediaEngine always run in 640x480 using DirectComposition

Tags: c++, windows, video, xbox-one

I am using **IMFMediaEngine** to playback video streams (Smooth Streaming, HLS) and possibly with **PlayReady** later.

It works wonderfully using **TransferVideoFrame** to draw the video onto a texture. But I understand that it is a requirement for PlayReady + DRM + 1080p videos, to use DirectComposition. So I am trying to make this works.

Also another advantage of doing it this way, the video frame rendering is independent from the app so possible stuttering or lag in the app UI won't affect the video playback.

I am able to make it work, but unfortunately the **IDCompositionVisual** I am using always end up being restricted to **640x480**. So the video has to downscale to it. Then if I transform this to scale it up, I get an ugly stretched picture.

I am registering the Visual this way:

```
pMediaAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_PLAYBACK_VISUAL, m_pDcompVideoVisual);
```

As documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162850(v=vs.85).aspx

Trying to create a surface prior and **SetContent** on the Visual doesn't change anything. It's like the video player override it with it's own surface, **640x480**. It would really be nice to stick it to the simple player, and find the real solution to this problem and be able to specify the size of the Visual Surface when I received the **MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_FORMATCHANGE** event.

Because this is an option in IMFMediaEngine to specify a DirectComposition surface, there must be a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docs I see for [IMFMediaEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should be able to handle DRM protected content using [IMFMediaEngineProtectedContent->TransferVideoFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447970(v=vs.85).aspx):

“*For protected content, call this method instead of the IMFMediaEngine::TransferVideoFrame method.*”

Something like this can go in the VideoPlayer::CaptureFrame method of the sample you provided:

```
// Transfer the frame to the texture
auto pIMFMediaEngineUnknown = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown *>(m_pMediaEngine);
IMFMediaEngineProtectedContent *temp = 0;
pIMFMediaEngineUnknown->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&temp));
DWORD flags = 0;
HRESULT ret = temp->TransferVideoFrame(m_pRenderTarget, &videoRect, &targetRect, &borderColor, &flags);
temp->Release();

//HRESULT ret = m_pMediaEngine->TransferVideoFrame(m_pRenderTarget, &videoRect, &targetRect, &borderColor);
assert(ret == S_OK && "Failed to transfer video frame");
```

Give this a shot with 1080p protected content.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got an hold of Microsoft support and they said the same thing. DirectComposition stopped working on Windows10 XboxOne for some reason. The DRM requirement was not a technical one, but a non-written rule apparently. So the programmer will never manipulate the frame directly. We are bringing up the issue higher to make sure that's still true.

Meanwhile, thanks for the answer that is the correct way of doing it.